# Resolving "an indented block" in Python

Tags: python, authentication, passwords

I'm an absolute amateur at coding in Python and I always end up getting this "IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'elif' statement on line 36" whenever I try to run my log-in program.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 # Gelos Enterpises Login 

import csv
import sys

import string
import random

import secrets

password_length = 10
print(secrets.token_urlsafe(password_length))

def main():
    menu()


def menu():
    print("************Gelos Enterpises Login**************")
    print()

    choice = input("""
                      A: Please Register
                      B: Login
                      C: Logout
                      D: Generate Password
        
                      Please enter your choice: """)

    if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
        register()
    elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
        login()
    elif choice == "C" or choice == "c":
        sys.exit

    elif choice == "D" or choice == "d":

    else:
        print("You must only select either A or B")
        print("Please try again")
        menu()


def register():
    pass


def login():
    pass


# the program is initiated, so to speak, here
main()
```

Comment: `elif choice == "D" or choice == "d":` You don't have any code underneath this statement.  You need _something_, even if it's just a do-nothing `pass` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
 # Gelos Enterpises Login 

import csv
import sys

import string
import random

import secrets

password_length = 10
print(secrets.token_urlsafe(password_length))

def main():
    menu()


def menu():
    print("************Gelos Enterpises Login**************")
    print()

    choice = input("""
                      A: Please Register
                      B: Login
                      C: Logout
                      D: Generate Password
        
                      Please enter your choice: """)

    if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
        register()
    elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
        login()
    elif choice == "C" or choice == "c":
        sys.exit

    elif choice == "D" or choice == "d":
    # The problem is here:
    # You need a statement here, if you want to do nothing, you could just use a pass
        pass
    else:
        print("You must only select either A or B")
        print("Please try again")
        menu()


def register():
    pass


def login():
    pass


# the program is initiated, so to speak, here
main()
python
authentication
```

Answer (score 0):

its because theres nothing in the elif block before that. If you don't want it to output anything just put a comment on that line

```
    elif choice == "C" or choice == "c":
        sys.exit

    elif choice == "D" or choice == "d":
        #this is your missing code!

    else:
        print("You must only select either A or B")
        print("Please try again")
        menu()
```